# substraction for two complement numbers

Tags: c++, c, binary

i have read that to subtract two number in two complement encoding, we just add them together.So why there is a ***sub*** instruction in assembly language for two complement numbers, there must be one for unsigned number only.

An expression like `5 - 7` is computed in that way : ??

-7 --> unsigned rep --> 0111 --> two complement -> 1001
then the computer do  --> 0101 + 1001 = 1110 = -2??

Comment: No, we don't just add them together.

Comment: so 0u -1, -1 is converted to unsigned (0xFF for 8 bits) and the computer compute 0x00 + 0xFF?? that right?

Comment: If you add two numbers, you get their *sum*, not their difference. That's why it's called "add".

Comment: i don't add them, its subtraction : **0u - 1**.

Comment: `1110 ` Note that the sign bit is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how complement works.

Consider the number -1234.

With 4 digits we'll represent it as

```
   10000
-   1234
```

which equals

```
    9999     + 1
-   1234
________
    8765     + 1
```

where 8765 is the **9's complement** (in the decimal system) of 1234, and 8765 + 1 = 8766 is the **10's complement** (in the decimal system).

To compute 5555 - 1234 you can simply do 10000 + 5555 - 1234 = 5555 + 8766. After calculating that, substract the 10000 again. And that's as simple as just ignoring the fifth digit.

You have just calculated a subtraction of 1234 by instead adding its 10's complement.

---

A subtraction operation for binary 2's complement form representation works by (1) computing the 2's complement, and (2) adding – which is different from just adding.

Answer (score 1):

The original post is correct. On a typical two's complement computer, the actual subtract operation produces the same result regardless if the numbers are signed or unsigned, so the actual subtract operation can assume unsigned numbers, but it sets two different conditional bits, setting or clearing a "borrow" bit assuming the numbers are unsigned, and setting or clearing an "overflow" bit assuming the numbers are signed.

Some processors use actual subtract hardware logic, instead of using negate and add.